# I can not use "Cloud Translation API" on Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I'm using Google Cloud Datalab and I got an error from this code

```
from google.cloud import translate
```

Error message is here

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d80fb3686483> in <module>()
----> 1 from google.cloud import translate

ImportError: cannot import name 'translate'
```

Does it mean I need to import module to Shell??

Answer (score 0):

The `google-cloud-translate` library is not in the [installed libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/key-concepts#included_libraries) of a Datalab instance. So, you need to install via pip first.

Try to execute the following command in a cell before importing it:

`!pip install google-cloud-translate`

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries) you can find more information on installing python dependencies in Datalab.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have already executed that command in a Cloud Shell from GCP
but still, the same error occurred. Do you have any other ideas??

Comment: Try installing it in a cell in the notebook where you want to use it. Jupyter notebooks can execute bash commands. The exclamation mark at the beginning is to indicate that the cell should interpret the command as bash

Comment: The reason for this is because if you installed it in Cloud Shell, that is not the same VM environment as your datalab VM.